# SQL Server Clone Tree Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, tree, clone, common-table-expression

I have a table Orgs(Id identity, Name , parent_id , country_id )
I need to Clone tree from a  country_id into another Country_id with CTE in sql server.
I wrote this SP.
Have anyone better solution?

```
Create procedure sp_clone_sub_orgs(@from_country_id as int , @to_country_id as int )
as 
declare @to_name as varchar(200) ;
declare @max as int ;
select @to_name = name from Countries where id = @to_country_id;
select @max =   MAX(ID) FROM orgs;
delete orgs where country_id= @to_country_id;
set identity_insert orgs on ;
SELECT
        row_number() over(order by id asc) as rn,
        ID,
        parent_id,
        name
INTO @Q
FROM orgs where country_id =@from_country_id

Insert into orgs (id ,  parent_id ,name,country_id)
Select 
        rn + @max as id 
        ,Isnull((select @max + rn from #Q q_temp where q_temp.id =q.parent_id),0) 
        ,Case When parent_id = 0 then @to_name else name end 
        ,@to_country_id as country_id
From #Q q;
set identity_insert orgs off ;
Drop Table @Q;
GO
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help -- as would an explanation of what *you* mean by "clone" in this context.

Comment: Typo: table #Q should be @Q.  Also, it's not necessary to set identity insert on and handle keys yourself.  The IDENTITY property of the table stores the current value and increments upon insert.

Comment: SteveC: He needs known ID values because the new rows have to refer to each other, as done by the scalar subquery for the value of the parent_id field

Comment: Thanks to  @Gordon Linoff ,I must describe "clone" as copy all rows (id , parent_id) saved in "Orgs" Table from from_country_id to to_country_id. suppose that the tree saved in source country is completed and we need to copy it's all rows into a new country_id and keep id,parent_id relationships  in new IDs.

Comment: I don't think the OP needs to assign the pk with "rn + @max as id".  The id which refers to the existing row is prefixed in the query by q_temp.